# Why does my entire site scale when I upload it to a web host?

Tags: html, css, localhost, web-hosting

When testing my site on my local computer, the proportions are correct; the images and widths are as I want them to be.

However, when I upload them to my web host, Dreamhost, it seems like the entire site is bumped up about 10% (the images, the font sizes, the sidebar width, etc). The scaling issue occurs in Firefox, Chrome, IE7-10, Safari, but also shows correctly when viewed locally.

The code is exactly the same. I've tried re-uploading images and testing my code but to no avail. I've never had an issue like this before... kinda stumped.

[image]

Comment: Most people want their website to scale! ;-)

Comment: Please compare HTML markup from both the sources. Also if possible, put them in post.

Comment: Might sound stupid, but have you tried Ctr/Cmd+0ing to see if the page was zoomed in prior?

Comment: +1 Flaxbeard: I spent 2 days trying to reproduce a bug a designer was reporting... she was just zoomed in.

Comment: `The scaling issue occurs in Firefox, Chrome, IE7-10, Safari, but also shows correctly when viewed locally.` What is your local browser? Is it one of these or older one?

Comment: Wow I feel like an idiot... the problem was the zoom. Bizarre that I didn't notice that I had zoomed in on all my browsers and virtual machine on this one specific page. Thanks Flaxbeard!

Comment: @Flaxbeard is right then. +1 :)

Comment: It depends on the browser. Most save the zoom settings based on domain according to my previous experience. Glad I could help!

Comment: @KevinChang - don't feel like an idiot. I've seen this exact issue cause hours of head scratching for professional testers. It's only obvious once you've seen it. It's very easy to accidentally change the zoom setting, and the browser really doesn't make it clear what it's done.

Answer (score 1):

you might zoomed in your site while on a local computer. when you upload it to a hosting site it displays it's default size view. so when making web pages don't zoom in or zoom out.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this thing happens, when the CSS programmer uses `em` rather than `px`. In some cases, the problem can be solved, especially in font issue, with a property: 100%. Like:

```
body{
font-size:100%;
}

p{
font-size:0.5em;
}
```

It'll set 100% for all the font properties, but will specify the font-size in the specific area, tag. The 100% will then lead the area, tag to set the resize in an exact proportion.
You can try the same thing (though no tested) for your `<img>` tag. Set a common property first, then set whatever you want.
*I'm not sure about it, but it's just a thought.* :)

Answer (score 0):

To complete [Mayeenul Islam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1743124/mayeenul-islam) answer I can add that it's always better to put a container inmediately after the body tag. It doesn't hurt and helps a lot. So instead of forcing the font 100% correction over every css style you could do it globally. Like this:

```
 <style>
 body { font-size:100% }
 #container { font-size:1em }
 </style>
```